# How can I override ANY plugin in my wordpress child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

There are some plugins that I can override in my child theme (e.g. woocommerce, BuddyPress, bbpress, etc). Usually creating a folder named the same as the plugin in the child theme root and making changes there. However, that doesn't always work for ANY plugin. I'd rather not make any structural changes in the plugin itself since it will be all gone on a plugin update. But I made a copy of the plugin in the child theme and it didn't do anything. How can I do this so that I can still get all the functionality I need from the main plugin and still have my alterations prevail?

Comment: Not all of the plugins allow you to override their files like that. It's actually only a handful of them (like WooCommerce for example.) For plugins that don't offer this feature (the vast majority I'd say) you'll need to check their documentation (if it exists) and use the action/filter hook(s) that are available (if any.)

Comment: Ah damn it. I was afraid of that answer. lol. thanks